# Undefined javascript function in Selenium test with Capybara

Tags: javascript, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a page with a Javascript function in HTML on the page:

```
 <body>
    ...


<script type="text/javascript">

    function myfunc(){
        // do smth
    }
</script>

 </body>
```

I'm using Capybara with Selenium Webdriver in my RSpec tests.

After visiting this page I want to call this function:

```
it "my test" do
  visit "http://example.com/mypage.html"

  page.execute_script "myfunc(); "

end
```

Almost all time this test is OK. But *sometimes* I get an error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: myfunc is not defined
```

How to fix this problem? Is it because Selenium is calling the function before the whole HTML page (with Javascript on it) is loaded ?

Comment: Did you try having the method on document load?

Comment: Do you mean execute a script like 
'page.execute_script "window.onload = function(e){ myfunc(); } "' ?

Comment: I meant having the page methods defined on document ready

Comment: thanks for the tip!  I don't want to touch the page and I don't want this function to be called after the page is loaded. I want to call this function from my test. I will try to call it ' page.execute_script '$(document).ready(function() { myfunc(); }); ' ' and see if it fails.

Comment: How about adding some re-try mechanism? That is, catch the "JavascriptError" error and add some wait (if error occurs), then once again call the function.